# Instalação Anaconda Python - Projetos PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, máquina-virtual

Utilizo o Windows 10 e, recentemente, me dei conta que meus arquivos e projetos desenvolvidos através da IDE PyCharm, bem como a instalação do pacote Anaconda, estão localizados em uma pasta no diretório que contém espaços (C:\Users\Thiago Panini). Acredito que esta nomeação esteja me causando alguns problemas que podem ser agravados no futuro. Falha minha na configuração.

Dito isso, resolvi criar um novo usuário no Windows com privilégios de administrador, só que dessa vez, sem espaços. Minha dúvida é: como já há um trabalho (razoavelmente vasto) realizado via PyCharm, qual seria a forma adequada para importar os projetos criados no antigo usuário para o novo usuário? Após essa importação, seria possível excluir os dados do usuário antigo? Há algum trauma nessa migração?

Realmente a ideia seria migrar para este novo usuário e descontinuar o antigo, dada esta falha na configuração.

Cheguei a pensar em criar uma VM para organizar o trabalho daqui pra frente, mas não sei se isso seria válido.

Muito obrigado.
Thiago Panini

Answer (score 0):

Você pode copiar a pasta do PyCharmProjecs, e colocar no diretório do PyCharm no novo usuario.

Você também pode criar uma VM, e dentro da mesma, colar a pasta dos projetos.

Uma vez que para acessa-los, tera que abrir a instancia da VM.